# The email doesn't render correctly in the Gmail app

Tags: css, email, media-queries, html-email, inline

I'm using a responsive template from Email on Acid to build my own template.

The problem is that on the Gmail App the template doesn't render properly.

Is there a way to make it work in the Gmail App as well? Thanks!

The Email can be found here

[link to the code](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_a_free_responsive_email_template_using_media_queries_-_part_i/)

This is how it looks in the Gmail app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcBii.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/usulu.jpg

This is how it should look like

https://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/free_template_1/graphic2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in my Litmus account and the only Gmail preview it was broken in and mimicked your results is the Gmail IMAP preview.
This is when Gmail is used to access another mailbox providers inbox.

So, say you have your work Outlook email setup in your smartphones Gmail app.
You basically have incompatible systems working together to serve you your email. Well, incompatible when it comes to things like this.

And this is outside of Gmail's hands really as the email is hitting your work email server (using my example above) and then being viewed in another providers app.

Comment: Unfortunately. it isn't. I have the Gmail app on my Android phone and the screenshot display is taken from there so it isn't Gmail IMAP preview

Comment: I use https://beefree.io/ to test the emails so if you paste the code there and send a test into your gmail account and check on your phone(android on my side) you will see the problem that I experience

Comment: But is the email address you're using in Gmail, a Gmail email address?
I've just used the Litmus provided tool, Putsmail - https://putsmail.com/tests, to send to my own Gmail account and viewed it on my phone. It renders perfectly fine.

Comment: Either you're using another email address in Gmail, or BeeFree is doing something funny.

Comment: Just tested out of BeeFree and it is definitely BeeFree causing the issue. I can;t pinpoint what it is, but it's potentially the server they're sending from, but that is just a guess and I'm not overly versed on how that affects email rendering.

Comment: Okay, when testing to my work Outlook and then pulling the source code and using Putsmail to send to my own Gmail, again the issue is evident. This is definitely a BeeFree platform/server issue.

Comment: BeeFree editor (or compiler before sending) might be messing up the media query maybe.  There is a dashes under the HTML to force desktop version with display none on it. FeeFree might be causing issues on that well?

Comment: I've tried sending it from salesforce and also campaignmonitor and I get the same result. Do you test it on an android phone?

Comment: Yes, using an Android phone. Up to date Gmail app. Which Gmail app test is that information pertaining to exactly though? They have four for Android and one for iOS. Only one is labelled as an IMAP version of the Gmail app. Here is the list: Gmail App - Android 6.0, Gmail App IMAP - Android 6.0, Gmail App - Android 7.1, Gmail App - Android 8.0, Gmail App - iOS 10.3.2.

Comment: As you can see, in that list there is a test specifically labelled IMAP. It definitely won't be a case that all Android Gmail app tests are using an IMAP account and the test results back that up when all Gmail tests are rendering fine and mimic what I'm seeing in my personal Gmail account, apart from the IMAP test preview which renders like yours.

Comment: If the platform you're testing from isn't the issue, as you've proven with the test of BeeFree, Salesforce and Campaign Monitor, then this points to the email address you're test sending to in your Gmail app.

Can you also confirm which Android version you're on?

Comment: I've tested it now with Litmus and it Litmus it does render fine but in the Android Gmail app on my phone and my colleagues phone its rendering as in the screenshot from the post

Comment: Ahh good to know you're seeing the same results. I think you'll need to look into your email address then. From my experience, with the testing from the platform issue mimicked from other platforms and the fact I'm seeing the same results as Litmus, this would only point to another service's email address being used in Gmail.

Comment: Gmail IMAP isn't a separate app. It is just a variation in the way the app renders an email. The distinction between the two is a) using a Gmail address (name@gmail.com), in Gmail or b) using a non Gmail account (name@outlook.com), in the Gmail.